# Is SSH remote debugging available for IntelliJ community edition ? If not, are there any alternatives?

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I need to work on a Spark application running on a remote server, on which I have access through SSH. At the moment, my team develop locally, compile the project with Maven, send it with SFTP to the server, run it from the terminal and read the logs to see if something went wrong. I would like to know if it is possible to link IntelliJ with the remote server and run Spark in debug mode so that I can debug remotely from IntelliJ, set breakpoints, etc. Is it possible ? I'm new to IntelliJ and I'm not sure to understand if this remote feature is only available in the ultimate edition. If it is the case, what other solution is there ? Thanks !

Comment: Remote JVM debug is available in Community Edition. Seems this article shows how to do it in IDEA: https://medium.com/agile-lab-engineering/spark-remote-debugging-371a1a8c44a8

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect IntelliJ remote debugger to your remote Spark application.
Actually, you can connect the debugger to a specific executor on which your application is being executed.
You need to follow the steps as @y.bedrov specified https://medium.com/agile-lab-engineering/spark-remote-debugging-371a1a8c44a8
In your case, i think the debugger is not connecting because you are specifying **localhost** as the host.
You need to replace it with the host on which the application is being executed, in other words the executor host.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for general-purpose java applications such as spring boot web apps. You could connect to an existing running process with idea and debug it the same way, as you debug your local application (the process on the remote server should be executed with a special key that allowed remote debugging).
But when you run the spark application in a cluster there is no particular process to connect to, because the resource manager selects one node as a driver and some other nodes as executors, start the application on the driver, and performs distributed operations on executors. So you actually don't know the address of the host, where your application will be executed.
Therefore you can't connect to it and debug it.
So the answer is no - you can't use remote debug with spark application at all.
But, you could start the spark session locally on your own PC and debug it.

Comment: I tried to open the ports with an SSH tunnel, and managed to makes the spark app wait for the debugger to connect (listening on the port 5005). However, IntelliJ could not connect (Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"). The error is different if I change the port, which makes me think that I can connect to the port but not with the executor. Could it be linked with what you are saying ? Is there a solution like running the spark app on a single executor ?